# Partial Differentiation After Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

We have a function $F(x, y, z) = 0$ and interested in $\frac{ \partial^2 x }{ \partial y \partial z} $. Would simply using partial differentiation after using implicit function theorem work? More precisely;

$\frac {\partial (-F_y / F_x)} { \partial z} = \frac{\partial (\partial x / \partial y)} {\partial z}=\frac {\partial^2 x} {\partial y \partial z} $

Is this correct?

Edit: Let me clarify with a quick example.

Suppose we have  $ x^2 + y^2z + z^3 = 0 $. Is the following correct?

$ F_x = 2x $

$ F_y = 2yz $

$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{-F_y}{F_x}= \frac{-yz}{x} $

$ \frac {\partial^2 x} {\partial y \partial z} = \frac{-y}{x} $

Comment: It's not actually clear what you were meant to do. But yes this "$\frac {\partial (-F_y / F_x)} { \partial z} = \frac{\partial (\partial x / \partial y)} {\partial z}=\frac {\partial^2 x} {\partial y \partial z} $" is valid.

Comment: Yes, this is also valid. You're simply using the implicit function theorem. So your result is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. What bothers me is that aren't we treating x as a function of y and z in $ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{-yz}{x} $? Is it correct to treat x as a constant while partially differentiating the result with respect to z? (Please note that I am only interested in determining the sign of the resulting equation)

Comment: When taking derivative of "$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{-yz}{x}$" with respect to $z$ in order to get $\frac {\partial^2 x} {\partial y \partial z}= \frac{-y}{x} $,  you are treating  $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{-yz}{x}$ as a function of $z$ whereas you treat $x$ and $y$ as constants. Hope it makes sense now..

Comment: Your answer is reassuring. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!